# Dynamic table options

Tags: c#, asp.net

I`m creating a dynamic HTML Table, the table content is from the database.
I think I can do it - but I have 2 question:

1. How I add a `<th>` to each column? I want to name to columns I have (CustomerId,ProductId, etc).
2. How can I click on a specific row?
   I want to click on a row and to be directed to a different page.

Note - I'm, not allowed to use DataTable - just HTML Table control.

This is my code:

```
    string SQL_Order_View = "SELECT * FROM Orders";
    SqlCommand SQLcmdOrders = new SqlCommand(SQL_Order_View, Conn);
    Conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader myOrders = SQLcmdOrders.ExecuteReader();
    while(myOrders.Read())
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tdCustomerId = new TableCell();
        TableCell tdProductId = new TableCell();
        TableCell tdPrice = new TableCell();

        tdCustomerId.Text = myOrders["CustomerId"].ToString();
        tdProductId.Text = myOrders["ProductId"].ToString();
        tdPrice.Text = myOrders["Price"].ToString();

        tr.Cells.Add(tdCustomerId);
        tr.Cells.Add(tdProductId);
        tr.Cells.Add(tdPrice);
        tblOrders.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
    Conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string SQL_Order_View = "SELECT * FROM Orders";
SqlCommand SQLcmdOrders = new SqlCommand(SQL_Order_View, Conn);
Conn.Open();
SqlDataReader myOrders = SQLcmdOrders.ExecuteReader();

// adding header
TableHeaderRow headRow = new TableHeaderRow();
TableHeaderCell thCustomerId = new TableCell();
TableHeaderCell thProductId = new TableCell();
TableHeaderCell thPrice = new TableCell();

thCustomerID.Text = "Customer ID";
thProductId.Text = "Product ID";
thPrice.Text = "Price";
tblOrders.Rows.Add(headRow );


while(myOrders.Read())
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tdCustomerId = new TableCell();
    TableCell tdProductId = new TableCell();
    TableCell tdPrice = new TableCell();

    tdCustomerId.Text = myOrders["CustomerId"].ToString();
    //tdProductId.Text = myOrders["ProductId"].ToString();
      //create clickable----
     HyperLink lnk= new HyperLink();
     lnk.ID = myOrders["ProductId"].ToString();
     lnk.NavigateUrl = "your url with some id here";
     tdProductId.Controls.Add(lnk);

    tdPrice.Text = myOrders["Price"].ToString();

    tr.Cells.Add(tdCustomerId);
    tr.Cells.Add(tdProductId);
    tr.Cells.Add(tdPrice);
    tblOrders.Rows.Add(tr);
}
Conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.How I add a  to each column**

```
// Create a TableHeaderRow.
TableHeaderRow headerRow = new TableHeaderRow();


// Create TableCell objects to contain 
// the text for the header.
TableHeaderCell headerTableCell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
TableHeaderCell headerTableCell2 = new TableHeaderCell();
TableHeaderCell headerTableCell3 = new TableHeaderCell();
headerTableCell1.Text = "CustomerId";
headerTableCell2.Text = "ProductId";
headerTableCell3.Text = "Price";


// Add the TableHeaderCell objects to the Cells
// collection of the TableHeaderRow.
headerRow.Cells.Add(headerTableCell1);
headerRow.Cells.Add(headerTableCell2);
headerRow.Cells.Add(headerTableCell3);

// Add the TableHeaderRow as the first item 
// in the Rows collection of the table.
tblOrders.Rows.AddAt(0, headerRow);
```

**2.How can to click on a specific row**

```
tr.Attributes["onclick"] = "<some javascript code here>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TableHeaderCell.

Additional information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheadercell.aspx